# Verify if username already exists with PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to check if a user name already exists in the database and I wrote this code

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['registrati'])) {

$Username = $_POST['nickname'];
$Password = md5($_POST['password']);
$Escape = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);
$Query2 = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE utenti='".$Username."'";
if(mysql_num_rows($Query2)>0) {
    echo "Nome utente già in uso";
}
else {
$Query = "INSERT INTO sito(usenti, password) VALUES('$Escape', '$Password')";
$Esecuzione = mysql_query($Query);
}
if(!$Esecuzione) {
    echo "Errore: ".mysql_error();
}
else { 
echo "";
}}
?>
```

When I run it, even if I put the same two user name, says nothing and puts them equally. Why?

Comment: are `utenti ` and `usenti` same?

Comment: you need to execute query before you run mysql_num_rows....and by the way, never use mysql_ any more, it's deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: $Query2 not executed?

Comment: Input error, that's not the problem

Comment: are you mixing up `sito` and `utenti`?

Comment: Where is $Query2 being executed before checking number of rows?

Comment: Consider using prepared/parmeterized queries with PDO or similar.  You will be able to avoid SQL injection much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your query before checking for number of rows returned `mysql_num_rows()`.

```
$result_set = mysql_query($Query2)
if(mysql_num_rows($result_set) > 0) {
    //continue
}
```

Sidenote: `MySQL_*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use `MySQLi_*` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a result as a parameter for mysql_num_rows.

So,

`$Query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE utenti='$Username'");`

instead of just the string

`$Query2 = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE utenti='$Username'";`

should fix it.

Note that you don't need to concat strings if you use double quotes.

Also, I strongly suggest you stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and switch to mysqli_* or PDO. See [the red box](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). And don't forget to ALWAYS sanitize your user input (or use prepared statements), because you're open to SQL injections otherwise.

Comment: I tried to do as you said but the problem remains and He also says:

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: You must've done something wrong... This has to work. `$Query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE utenti='$Username'"); if(mysql_num_rows($Query2)>0) {...`

Comment: Still not working. In Database inserts Nickname even if present twice. I'm going crazy

Comment: Then something's wrong with the inserted nicknames, and the SELECT statement doesn't return any rows. Check your db.

Answer (score 0):

execute the query2 beforre `mysql_num_rows($Query2)`

like this,

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE utenti='".$Username."'")
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {//code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed

```
mysql_query($Query2)
```

before if condition.

You should try to use PHP Data Objects (PDO) to connect to database and avoid using mysql extension. mysql_ functions is deprecated in php 5.5.0 version and will be removed in future.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to insert and retrieve the same columns from the same table. YOu are inserting into column `usenti` of table `sito`, but retrieving `utenti` from table `utenti`. I assume this is a typo.
2. You store the username with `$Escape`, you should retrieve with the same.
3. You need to perform `mysql_query($Query2)` to execute the actual query before you can check for number of rows.

Try the following fixes:

```
$Query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM sito WHERE usenti='".$Escape."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($Query2)>0) {
   echo "Nome utente già in uso";
}
```